# Working Set Algorithm and Virtual Memory

Tags: virtual-memory, working-set

Working Set algorithm: There are 2 processes, each one of them has its own working set window. According to theory, in that window are stored the Δ most recent pages that the process has asked for.

My problem is this: When a page must be brought to the window, are we moving that page directly from the disk (Disk -> Windown) meaning there's no need for virtual memory; or, there should be an inverted page table, that stores the pages, so that we move it from there (Disk -> Inverted Page Table -> Window).

Long question short: Is the WS algorithm connected (in any way) with the Inverted Page Table

-Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are confused here.

1) Inverted Page Tables are simply a mechanism for implementing page tables (logical memory translation). For learning how virtual memory works, you can ignore inverted page tables.

2. If you move a page from disk to physical memory, you are using virtual memory.

So, no the WS is not connected with Inverted Page Tables.